# Unexpected execution order in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-ajax

I'm writing a couple of functions calling each other in js and I found a unexpected (by me) behaviour in the order of execution.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function rellenarProveedores() {

        var dProveedores = document.getElementById('Proveedor');
        var proveedorActual = document.getElementById('proveedorActual').value;

        while (dProveedores.options.length > 0) {
            dProveedores.remove(0);
        }

        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.text = 'SELECCIONAR PROVEEDOR';
        opt.value = '';
        dProveedores.appendChild(opt);

        var url = '/Incidencias/ObtenerProveedores';
        var array = lecturaBD(url);

        alert('LECTURA OBTENIDA: '+array);

        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

            var opt = document.createElement('option');
            var obj = array[i];
            opt.text = obj.Nombre;
            opt.value = obj.ProveedorID;
            if (obj.ProveedorID == proveedorActual) {
                opt.selected = true;
            }
            dProveedores.appendChild(opt);
        }
    }

    function lecturaBD(param) {

        var enviarData;
        var salida;


        $.ajax({
            url: param,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json;',
            data: enviarData,
            success: function (data) {
                alert('LECTURA BD: '+data);
                salida = data;
            },
            error: function (data) { alert('Error'); }
        });

        return salida;
    }

    window.onload = function () { rellenarProveedores() };

</script>
```

According to the calls I make, I was expecting to see:

1. alert('LECTURA BD: '+data);
2. alert('LECTURA OBTENIDA: '+array);

However, the order is completely the oposite and it causes a failure in my result.  Is there any logical reason for this?

As an extra information, I am using it in .net MVC and Chrome.

Comment: Ajax is **Asynchronous**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax is asynchronous and will not execute immediately. It will wait for the request on `/Incidencias/ObtenerProveedores` to complete before executing. That's why your `LECTURA OBTENIDA` alerts first. The `LECTURA BD` was still waiting at that time.

You should put everything you need after the Ajax on a callback:

```
function rellenarProveedores() {
    var dProveedores = document.getElementById('Proveedor');
    var proveedorActual = document.getElementById('proveedorActual').value;

    while (dProveedores.options.length > 0) {
        dProveedores.remove(0);
    }

    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.text = 'SELECCIONAR PROVEEDOR';
    opt.value = '';
    dProveedores.appendChild(opt);

    var url = '/Incidencias/ObtenerProveedores';
    lecturaBD(url, function(array){
        alert('LECTURA OBTENIDA: '+array);

        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            var opt = document.createElement('option');
            var obj = array[i];
            opt.text = obj.Nombre;
            opt.value = obj.ProveedorID;
            if (obj.ProveedorID == proveedorActual) {
                opt.selected = true;
            }
            dProveedores.appendChild(opt);
        }
    });
}

function lecturaBD(param, callback) {
    var enviarData;
    $.ajax({
        url: param,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json;',
        data: enviarData,
        success: function( response ) {
            alert('LECTURA BD: '+data);
            callback( response );
        },
        error: function (data) { alert('Error'); }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're making an ajax call which will return immediately (without having called your ajax success function), then it will return from your lecturaBD function and then run `alert('LECTURA OBTENIDA: '+array);`  When the server responds (whenever that might happen) then your ajax success function will run.

You probably want to create a specific function to put as your ajax success function.  In that function you could put this code:

```
        alert('LECTURA OBTENIDA: '+array);

        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

            var opt = document.createElement('option');
            var obj = array[i];
            opt.text = obj.Nombre;
            opt.value = obj.ProveedorID;
            if (obj.ProveedorID == proveedorActual) {
                opt.selected = true;
            }
            dProveedores.appendChild(opt);
        }'
```

Then that code will not run until the server responds.